# epstopdf writes faulty pdfs if a large number of files are converted with a batch file

Tags: epstopdf

If I want to convert a lot of eps files into pdf from a batch file (approx. 3200) then it happens again and again that some pdfs are invalid. If I convert them individually, a valid pdf will come out.
What can this be?

epstopdf log entry for an invalid pdf (file paths shortened):

> 2021-01-14 15:48:29,303+0100 INFO  epstopdf - this process (24156) started by 'cmd' with command line: C:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\epstopdf.exe "auto61.eps" --pdf-version=1.5 --nocompress
> 2021-01-14 15:48:29,487+0100 INFO  epstopdf.core - start process: mgs.exe -dUseFlateCompression=false -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 "-sOutputFile=auto61.pdf" - -c quit
> 2021-01-14 15:48:30,948+0100 INFO  epstopdf - this process (24156) finishes with exit code 0

and the pdf looks like this (I have replaced the stream content with XXX)

> %PDF-1.5
> %Çì¢
> 5 0 obj
> <</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
> stream
> XXX
> endstream
> endobj
> 6 0 obj
> 2039
> endobj

EDIT:

Non "working" epstopdf version:

> MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter 4.0 (MiKTeX 20.12)

"Working" version:

> MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter 2.9.6050 (MiKTeX 2.9)

Comment: Report it in the MiKTeX issue tracker.

Comment: Reported [MiKTeX issue tracker](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/687)